# PizzaShop - DB - Normalized Schema

Tags: database-design, schema

I am trying to make a simple DB in Access for a theoretical pizza shop(the db is for an assignment). What I am trying to do is link one type of pizza to one or more types of toppings. I just wanted a second opinion. Here's the schema:

[image: My schema]

Comment: This schema can't cope with someone wanting a Hawaiian with extra cheese and a Hawaiian with mushrooms. Pizza&Orders&Toppings should join to Order&Pizzas and Toppings.

Comment: Don't use spaces in column names. I know you can, but it just makes life harder

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Be concistent within your columnnaming! In Type you use ID, in Customer you use CustID and in Orders CusomerID. Same with ToppingID vs ToppingCode. And you dont have to use the Prefix Pizza in the Pizzas (imho, plural is also not that nice) table.

The relation *Type* is not clear to me. I guess you can put the OrderType directly into *Orders*.

You also can think about to remove the PizzaCode Column from *Pizzas&Orders&Toppings*. You can get this information from *Orders* join *Order&Pizzas*.

Edit: I guess Time is for the planned delivery time. Therefore you should name it like that. Otherwise you get confused with Date

Comment: Thanks! :D I am really new to this so I'm still making a bunch of mistakes.